Supertrend Indicator
I'm trying to implement the Supertrend indicator. Unfortunately, I can't calculate the values ​​that my chart software generates. At the moment, I don't fully understand my problem.
You can add the Average True Range and Supertrend indicators here and look at the stock prices, but the values ​​don't add up (Chart ).
The formula to calculate the Supertrend should be:
if Close > (H + L) / 2:
(H + L) / 2 + M * ATR
else:
(H + L) / 2 - M * ATR
For example values to calculate the supertrend provided by the charting software would be:



Date
Open
High
Low
Close
Supertrend
ATR




01.05.22
13996.82
14589.45
13380.67
14388.35
13834.08
1226.26


01.06.22
14478.37
14709.38
12618.68
12783.77
16180.90
1312.71



With the formula I would calculate 16437.58 (instead of 13834.08) and 11038.61 (instead of 16180.90). Can anyone help?

What source/reference material are you using for Supertrend? I tried to use https://www.quantifiedstrategies.com/supertrend-indicator-trading-strategy/ but TBH I was not completely able to reproduce the published results either.  (Maybe U and I should compare our work so far).

For example:
https://www.investopedia.com/supertrend-indicator-7976167
There are much more tutorials. One reference suggests a different calculation if the close price is above or under the base price (= (high + low) / 2). If the close price is higher than the base price, we must calculate: (high + low) / 2 + 2 * ATR; if the close price is lower than the base price, we must calculate (high + low) / 2 - 2 * ATR.
My attempt in LibreOffice Calc with
C2 = High
D2 = Low
E2 = Close
F2 = ATR
P2 = 2
is
=IF( E2 > (C2+D2) / 2 ; (C2 + D2) / 2 + $P$2 * F2; (C2 + D2) / 2 - $P$2 * F2)
